# Not enough parameters for the SQL statement error

Tags: python, sql, database, csv, mysql-connector-python

i'm trying to import csv file into SQL table  but i received this error "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement" i think that it's something in the SQL query ...

```
import mysql.connector as msql
import csv

conn = msql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='test_database')
my_cursor = conn.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(open('lycee.csv'))
header = next(csv_data)

print('Importing the CSV Files')
 for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lycee(date,etudiant,universite,age) 
      VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%d)", row)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is shown when you print row? try with something like  values =[row['date'],row['etudiant'],row['universite'],row['age'] or check the length of row

Comment: when i print row it show like this ['2000-01-06;malek;nante;22'] , it just takes the first row of my file and don't continue for others

Comment: You need to open the file and after that read it.... Update your code like this:         
with open('lycee.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader:
print(row )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lycee(date,etudiant,universite,age) 
  VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%d)", row)
```

Row is an list or dictionary here. You're asking for 4 parameters to be provided but only provide 1 to place them on there.

Row would be something like this:

```
[2020-01-01,me,universityname,32]
```

So something like:

```
row[0]
```

could provide the date, assuming the output of the csv.reader is a list of lists. Do the same for the other values as well.

Comment: when i print row it show like this ['2000-01-06;malek;nante;22'] , it just takes the first row of my file and don't continue for others , i don't understand what type must be row to inset it into the table ?

Comment: Different issue, but most likely you need for row in csv_data.readlines OR (as in your example is shown) you need to set the delimiter to semicolon instead of comma.

Comment: have you an idea how can i change the delimiter from semicolon to comma , i tried some solutions but don't work

Comment: Simply add an additional argument to your csv.reader like delimiter=";" should work.

Answer (score 1):

Asssuming `lycee.csv` has 4 columns

When you do

```
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lycee(date,etudiant,universite,age) 
    VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%d)", row)
```

you actually pass 1 array argument, but 4 expected. All you need to do is to unwrap your array

```
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lycee(date,etudiant,universite,age) 
  VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%d)", *row)
```

Comment: Ow, this answer is even better. Upvoted.